# How to wirelessly connect Apple devices (iPad or iPhone) to Xcode without connecting the device to the Macbook using USB cable?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want to wirelessly debug my app. How do I wirelessly connect my iPad to Xcode? It is required of me to connect my device to my Macbook using USB cable first, but my USB port is not working at all and it is impossible for me to do so. I looked everywhere on the web but cannot seem to get it working.

Here is what I get when I go to Window -> Devices and Simulators:

[image]

I tried clicking on "+" at the bottom left to see if my iPad connected:

[image]

Is there a way for me to connect my device using IP address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Xcode help documentation it states:

> Before you can launch your app on a wireless device, you must pair the device with Xcode.

And then in the same documentation it gives instructions on how to pair the device where it states:

> Connect the iOS device to your Mac with a lightning cable.

So, in short, in order to get wireless debugging to work you have to connect the device using a wire the first time.

AFTER you have paired the device with Xcode using a wire, you should see something like this (image taken from Apple's help docs) in Devices and Simulators.

[Enable wireless debugging with a paired device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmsxz.png)

Once this pairing has taken place the device will show up in Devices and Simulators whether it is connected or not.

At this stage if the device does not connect automatically then there is a way to connect via ip address by right clicking on the device in Devices and Simulators:

[Connecting to disconnected (paired) device via IP address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhlg9.png)

Comment: I am still wrapping my head around the *why* of needing the first connection by wire. It makes little sense unless you simply figure they did this to help the accessory markets.

Comment: @drew..The why isn't really relevant here, but I doubt it had anything to do with the accessory market. Much more likely to be caused by something like technical constraints, security concerns, laziness, or the good old "haven't gotten around to implementing that yet". There are always things that could be better about software, they don't always get implemented.

Comment: I have the problem, that my devices (iPad and iPhone) keep popping on and of when I connect them by cable. I somehow managed to get my iPhone connected via wifi but can't get this done with my iPad.
  I tried different cables but this did not help. Strangely enough they connect fine to my wife's MacBook. I use Xcode 13 and iOS 15.3.1 on Big Sur 11.6.5 (MacBook Pro 2014 won't run on Monterey). 
  Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Ki_ rebooting the iOS devices usually helps me in those cases. You may have more difficulty soon as Xcode 13.3 requires Monterey.

Comment: @Helam thanks for the suggestion, I will try it, if I run into the problem again. About Monterey: yes, I thought of this either and already upgraded to a newer machine.